# How can I abort a Windows Installer using VB Script?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vbscript, installation, setup-project

How can I abort a Windows Installer using VB Script that when it choose a certain option, the installer will force end?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project:

Here is the pseudocode for it:

```
MSGBOX "Do you want to continue installing?"
 IF Press YES { Continue Installing }
 If Press NO { Abort/Exit the installation process. }
End
```

I expect this final window to appear after I press NO:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you said something about what the incorrect option is. It might be something in a dialog (like TextBoxes) that you've added to the UI and you can't validate it because VS setups have no support for custom actions to run during the UI to validate entered data.

Either way, all custom actions in VS setups run after all the files are installed and the setup is virtually complete. In other words the only place to validate your data is after the install has finished when it's too late to stop the installation. All you can do is return an error from the VB Script and have the whole setup abort and roll back, and I don't think that's what you want.

If you really need this kind of functionality you need a tool that has support for it, somewhere in the dozens of tools that can create MSI files.

In a more functional tool I don't think you'd use a dialog choice like that. The dialog that offered the choice would have a custom action validate the data when the Next button is clicked. If the data is incorrect then the Next button stays disabled. If it is potentially incorrect a warning can appear on the dialog, but there is a Cancel-type button on every install dialog I've seen, so you don't need to abort anything - tell the user to cancel. But most dialogs have a back button to go back and change data too. In other words your UI flow isn't typical of most wizard-type flows in installs and therefore could be confusing.